# Installing grails templates not giving scaffolding

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

Okay perhaps something changed that I dont know about OR I am missing a step.

Several weeks ago in a grails app I did   `grails install-templates` as mentioned here http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html  and I got a `artifacts` `scaffolding` `testing` and `war` folders with items in them.

However today I am getting `artifacts` `testing` and `war`.  Is there something I am missing?

For this project I really only need a CRUD app and am fine with the generated views but there are a few tweaks for style that I need to do.

We are using Grails 2.3.7

Comment: Is this an upgraded Grails application or a green-field 2.3.7 application?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Not quite sure what you mean as I am new to grails but...   This is a newly created app.   I created it from within netbeans if that makes a difference.

Comment: I can confirm the same behavior with a brand new (green-field) Grails 2.3.7 application. Up voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, apparently there is the need to run `refresh-dependencies` before running `install-templates`. I was able to verify this in 2.3.7.

This was noted on the developers [mailing list](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-2-3-install-templates-and-scaffolding-folder-td4649143.html).

Comment: Interesting as I don't remember doing the refresh-dependencies last time but I will give it a go.  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what changed, but apparently something did. Glad we found the workaround.